# Bool to Byte in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a boolean variable which has value true, i want to convert it to byte.

What would the best way to do it.

`val bool = true`

I want the byte type and byte value of variable bool in scala.

Answer (score 1):

```
val res: Byte = if (bool) 1 else 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it this way:

```
val bool = true
val booleanToByte = (b: Boolean) => (if (b) 1 else 0).toByte
val byteValue = booleanToByte(bool)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want some interchangeability of `Byte`/`Bool` values, you have an option to use implicit conversions ( yet it is something to consider as *unsafe* )

Ammonite:

```
@ implicit def asBool(src: Byte): Boolean = src > 0 
defined function asBool
@ implicit def asByte(src: Boolean): Byte = if (src) 1 else 0 
defined function asByte
@ val xxx: Byte = true 
xxx: Byte = 1
@ val yyy: Boolean = 0.toByte 
yyy: Boolean = false
```

This also works with the functions:

```
@ def takeByte(x: Byte): Byte = x 
defined function takeByte
@ takeByte(false) 
res8: Byte = 0
@ takeByte(true) 
res9: Byte = 1
```

Hope that helps.